# How to arc patch a preview diff

Tags: arcanist

I created a diff (rather than revision) using `arc diff --preview` on one machine and I'd like to patch it on another machine. What command do I use? If I try `arc patch <ID>` I get:

```
Exception
The diff or revision you specified is either invalid or you don't have
permission to view it.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct command to run is `arc patch --diff <ID>`. The difference is that when you use `arc patch <ID>` it's referring a revision ID rather than a diff ID.